# DataGrid fails to commit edits upon view unload

Tags: wpf, datagrid, .net-4.5

My main viewmodel encapsulates a set of workspace viewmodels only one of which is exposed at any given time via a CurrentWorkspace property on the main view model. The user gets to switch between workspaces through a series of radio buttons so that when a radio button is clicked, the value of the CurrentWorkspace is replaced with a new workspace viewmodel.

Each workspace has a corresponding view (datatemplate) so that as workspaces are switched, old view unloads and a new view loads in keeping with the value of CurrentWorkspace property. Now each view has a datagrid that could still be in edit mode when the user may choose to click a radio button forcing view unload that dismantles its visual tree including the datagrid. The problem is that the last pending row edit is not committed to the underlying view model when this happens.

I tried to remedy the situation by trying to handle DataGrid LostFocus, LostKeyboardFocus, Unload events as well as the UnloadingRow event but none of them seem to offer a handle to the issue. It seems that once the view unload is triggered, these events either do not fire or fire too late for me to invoke a commit.

I would appreciate any help or pointer to where I should look to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I noted above was only observed when the user clicked RadioButton triggering view unload. However, there are other buttons in the main view that also trigger workspace unload (such as Quit button) but those surprisingly did not produce the same bug.

On close scrutiny I found, that radio buttons had by design set their attribute Focusable=False. Undoing it solves my problem and the datagrid now commits edits properly when the view unloads. As I noted above, DataGrid/DataGridRow LostFocus events were not firing as expected and now I believe I found the reason.

So I guess DataGrid/DataGridRow rely on their LostFocus events to trigger commits and its important that this event be not suppressed in any manner. I still wish though if wpf controls had an "Unloading" event as a fall back option to handle problems created by design decisions like the one in my case.